# CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST error when building xamarin.android using Multidex

Tags: android, xamarin, android-multidex

**Edit - Reduced to the root of the problem**

I'm getting this error when Multi-Dex is enabled.

> CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : error : Expecting class path separator ':' before '.jar' in argument number 2

I have tracked it down to this jar file being included in the ProGuard command line:

```
obj/Debug/__library_projects__/DeviceAPI_Android/library_project_imports/DeviceAPI_Android.Jars.cw-deviceapi(2016.05.16).jar
```

It's the brackets in the file name which are causing the error. I've proved this by running the command in a terminal prompt with this jar file removed, and all works fine.

So the question - where is this file coming from? Is it in Packages? I can't see it there.

If I can find that I should be able to correct the name and build the project.

I've tracked it down to a 3rd party binding library called DeviceAPI_Android.dll, which wraps a jar file for controlling the hardware barcode scanner. The jar file does indeed have the brackets and date in its filename.

So the solution is one or more of:

- Get a new version of the binding library from the supplier with a better named jar file.
- Rebuild the library myself with a better named jar file. Potentially problematic because I'll have to create the transforms etc. from scratch.
- Adjust the build tooling/makefile to make the ProGuard command line more resilient to strangely named jar files.

A sample project demonstrating the problem is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/MicrosecLtdUk/MultiDexTest).

**Version Information:**
=== Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac ===

Version 7.1 (build 1297)
Installation UUID: 650b4c91-c7f5-4ee5-ad70-6f178f314906
Runtime:
    Mono 5.2.0.215 (d15-3/da80840) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

```
Package version: 502000215
```

=== NuGet ===

Version: 4.3.0.2418

=== .NET Core ===

Runtime: Not installed
SDK: Not installed
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.2.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.5.5
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 7.4.0.21 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/jameslavery/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        2.3   (API level 10)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.1   (API level 16)
        4.3   (API level 18)
        4.4   (API level 19)
        5.0   (API level 21)
        5.1   (API level 22)
        6.0   (API level 23)
        7.0   (API level 24)
        7.1   (API level 25)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.5
SDK Platform Tools Version: 25.0.5
SDK Build Tools Version: 25.0.3

Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 8.0 (11246)
Build 8A218a

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 10.12.0.20 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 80b8487d
Branch: d15-3
Build date: 2017-08-18 16:07:26-0400

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 3.6.0.19 (Visual Studio Community)

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.2.2
Hash: b71b035
Branch: d15-1
Build date: Fri, 21 Apr 2017 17:57:12 GMT

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 701001297
Git revision: 9c5299666538b2f8baf501418a5c064d784d64da
Build date: 2017-08-07 11:29:35-04
Xamarin addins: 3bb0c32a14f1b7e368bf5ac53a84c3581c019391
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-3

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.11.6
Darwin 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0
    Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016
    root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

=== Enabled user installed addins ===

LiveXAML 1.0
Redth's Addins 1.0.9

Comment: Make sure to clear your local build cache (`bin/obj` folders). Secondly, upload a diagnostic build output log to your post so we can see what tools are being picked up. Thanks!

Comment: Tried clearing bin/obj (and doing a 'clean' before this, and then exiting Visual Studio) - doesn't fix it unfortunately. This is the first thing I tried!

Comment: I've uploaded diagnostic build output. I've also tried enabling both ProGuard and Multi-Dex - same problem. I was assuming previously that if we are using Multi-Dex we don't need ProGuard.

Comment: I've also added the specific build output pertaining to ProGuard in my post.

Comment: You shouldn't have to enable both items to get either effect (Proguard - Code Shrinking / Multidex - Overfill dex files). From a glance, this `proguard.jar` invocation looks like it will fail. Since I do not have this project locally(This would be the next step), I would advise you to run the `proguard.jar` command manually and see if better output is thrown or the same error is. If so, we can look through each `.jar` declaration to ensure there is a `:` separator.

Comment: If you aren't sure what command that is, it's the line above the error you posted in your question. i.e. `/usr/bin/java -jar /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mandroid/proguard/lib/proguard.jar ...`

Comment: Thanks - that was my next question... I assume I need to run this in an SDK command prompt.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce the same error 'Error: Expecting class path separator ':' before '.jar' in argument number 2' running the command in Terminal. So progress. Now to work out where the command line syntax is wrong.

Comment: Additionally, if you can create a non-sensitive project that demonstrates this behavior(Probably just the same packages) and can send to me(Or upload to this question), we can get this filed away and some eyes on this. I'd have to dig further using my own tactics to see WHY this is happening.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try to put something together over the weekend.

Comment: The problem is brackets in one of the imported library jars: obj/Debug/__library_projects__/DeviceAPI_Android/library_project_imports/DeviceAPI_Android.Jars.cw-deviceapi(2016.05.16).jar

Comment: Can you rename this jar? It seems like you might have control to do this.

Comment: Not directly. I've established that it's the embedded jar file from a binding library for the native scanner. I can rename it and build a new binding library - I think that's my best bet.

Comment: Or I might be able to edit the make file for the build to escape the arguments so the brackets don't break the command line.

Comment: The problem with redoing the binding library is that I am unlikely to end up with the same transforms etc as the original authors. This may affect the external endpoints/methods.

Comment: If I can get my hands on a similar example (If this is a public library), we can get a bug reported and see if our tooling can fix anything here. From a glance, it looks more related to Android tooling than Xamarin given the command line fails.

Comment: Knowing the problem, I can now produce a sample project which exhibits the problem. If we can make the tooling cope better with this situation that would be great.

Comment: Main post updated with description of root cause, and a link to a sample project added.

Comment: James, What version of Xamarin tooling do you currently have installed? I can't seem to replicate the error on 15.3.3 (Xamarin.Android 7.4.0.21).

Comment: Jon - thanks. I've added full version information to the post.

Comment: Ah perfect, I can now replicate. I will followup with a bug report number that you can CC yourself to.

Comment: Excellent - thank you very much. Interestingly this isn't a problem on Windows because Multi-Dex doesn't use ProGuard to get its list of classes (I think - you're the expert!). But OS X build/deploy is _so_ much faster than Windows....

Answer (score 0):

I have reported the following bug for this issue:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59237

Please feel free to CC yourself to this issue to be notified when it gets fixed. For the time being, you will have to workaround this by renaming the .jar in some fashion.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is a binding library with an embedded Jar file with brackets in its filename - which cause the command line for ProGuard to fail.

@jondouglas has submitted [Xamarin bug 59237](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59237) for this. Hopefully the fix will be to make the command line for ProGuard more resilient to strangely named files.

In the meantime, I will have to get hold of an updated binding library with the embedded jar file not having a name with parentheses (or other character which breaks a command line) in it.

Thanks to @jondouglas for his help in diagnosing the problem.