# Where do Xamarin.Android __library_projects__/DeviceAPI_Android/library_project_imports files come from?

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a problem with my Xamarin.Forms android project building when Multi-Dex is being used.

My original post relating to the problem is here:[post relating to MULTIDEX error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991435/createmultidexmaindexclasslist-error-when-building-xamarin-android-using-multide).

The root problem is with this file which has been copied to my obj/Debug folder:

```
obj/Debug/__library_projects__/DeviceAPI_Android/library_project_imports/DeviceAPI_Android.Jars.cw-deviceapi(2016.05.16).jar
```

The brackets in the filename are causing ProGuard.jar to fail.

I can't work out where this file is coming from - it's presumably to do with the Device API on Android (duh!). Where should I be able to find the source file? Presumably somewhere in my Xamarin Android SDK folders. However I can't find it.

Can someone point me to where I can find it?

Comment: Do you have a 3rd-party package/library that is including `DeviceAPI-Android`?

Comment: Aha! Thank you for making me look in the right place. We've got a device-specific reference to DeviceAPI_Android.dll for barcode scanning. The name looks too much of a coincidence. The next problem is to work out where the .jar file is coming from. I presume it's embedded in this 3rd party DLL.

Comment: It would be embedded as a resource in the Xamarin.Android Binding library that is a "normal" nuget package reference. During the build routine, these are extracted in order to package into the app (and to be available for proguard squashing and multidex creation), thus it would be embedded in `DeviceAPI_Android.dll`

Comment: That's what I was assuming (I've done Xamarin bindings in the distant past). So it looks like I need to rebuild this binding library with a better named embedded .jar file.

Comment: yes ;-) .......

Comment: Hmm... I don't have the source with that badly named jar file. I wonder if I can use ildasm or similar to just rename the resource in the dll...

Answer (score 0):

This file is coming from a 3rd party Xamarin binding library called *DeviceAPI_Android.dll* - it's the deflated .jar resource which the binding library is wrapping.

Thanks @SushiHangover for the pointer as to where to look.

So to fix my other problem - of the filename causing ProGuard to fail - I need to get the supplier to rebuild the library with a better named .jar file, or to adjust the build task to escape the ProGuard command line to cope with the brackets in the .jar filename.